# Setting Default on Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, upgrade-script

I'm using the following for an mysql update. It is adding the column correctly however it is not defining the default. It keeps it setting default to NULL. Any suggestions on where I am going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('admin/user'), 'enable_subclass', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        'default'   => '0',
        ), 'Admin Sub-Class Status');


$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `addColumn` in `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql`

```
    $installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('admin/user'), 'enable_subclass', array(
        'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'default'   => '0',
        'comment'   => 'Admin Sub-Class Status'
    ));
```